# ATX PSU 3.3V output dead short with ground

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ground, atx

On an ATX PSU, 3.3V output was dead short with ground (checked with DMM),once i powered ON the PSU  3.3V output was providing the rated output (3.3V) how this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows how your particular PSU works internally, and the schematic is usually not public available.

But typically, an ATX PS delivers about 20-25A on the 3.3V rail. If it were a simple transformer, the wire on the 3.3V side would be quite short and thick. Now, a power supply is more complex. There is a rectifier, typically made of schottky diodes. They already have low forward voltages of about 0.4V, but if your DMM draws a really small test current in the order of 1mA through a diode which is made for >20A, the voltage drop can be negligible, and your DMM won't notice the Diode.

Last, there is a quite large capacitor (several mF) right before the output, and if you attach your DMM, the cap will look like a short circuit for a several seconds.

Finally, your question is a bit like *I have a 3000W motor which works fine. How is it possible that I can easily turn the shaft by hand when power is off?*